# Android animations - Translate and Scale don't work properly

Tags: android, animation, translate, translate-animation

I made a little method to translate a view above another view and scale to that view's size.

Method works, but it translate the view with a margin.
This is the method:

```
public AnimationSet getFromToAnimation(View from, View to, final Runnable onEnd){
    AnimationSet animationSet = new AnimationSet(true);
    animationSet.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    animationSet.setFillEnabled(true);
    animationSet.setDuration(3000);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams fromParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) from.getLayoutParams();
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams toParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) to.getLayoutParams();
    float tx = (to.getX() + toParams.leftMargin) - (from.getX() + fromParams.leftMargin);
    float ty = (to.getY() + toParams.topMargin) - (from.getY() + fromParams.topMargin);
    TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, tx,0, ty);

    float x = (float) to.getWidth() / (float) from.getWidth();
    float y = (float) to.getHeight() / (float) from.getHeight();
    ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(1f, x, 1f, y,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f);

    animationSet.addAnimation(translateAnimation);
    animationSet.addAnimation(scaleAnimation);
    animationSet.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            onEnd.run();
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
    });
    return animationSet;
}
```

Then I use it like this

```
LinearLayout lnrFrom = findViewById(R.id.lnr_game_operation);
LinearLayout lnrTo = findViewById(R.id.lnr_game_operation_old);
AnimationSet animation = getFromToAnimation(lnrFrom, lnrTo, new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ...
    }
});
lnrFrom.startAnimation(animation);
```

And this is xml with many layouts, which I need to start the animation

```
<LinearLayout
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lnr_game_operation_old"
        android:background="@drawable/operation"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dp100"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp60">...</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lnr_game_operation"
        android:background="@drawable/operation"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dp120"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp70">...</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lnr_game_operation_new"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:background="@drawable/operation"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dp100"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp60">...</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Does anyone know another method to do this or why it doesn't work?

Comment: Please show how you use the AnimationSet

Comment: @BömachtBlau Ok, I edited the question (sorry for my bad English)

Comment: The translation (the path which the View has to travel) seems to be scaled together with the View: if the View should shrink, it does not move all the way to cover the other View. If it should grow, it overshoots and moves out of the screen. I've no idea why this happens. You asked for "another method" - is it important for you to keep the LinearLayout? And you may have noticed that the whole ViewGroup shrinks (or grows) with the scale animation, this includes also text size, not only the outer bounds of the ViewGroup. Do you consider this to be a bug or a feature?